# Meteor.js app running locally throwing TypeError: Cannot read property 'appId' of undefined

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, meteor

Brand new to meteor, have only ever used rails.  A friend gave me her app to mess around with.  When I run `meteor run` in the console, and load `localhost` I get the following error message in the browser.  I am finding I cant understand the error message. Could someone please assist me in understanding it?

```
/Users/mainuser/.meteor/packages/meteor-tool/.1.4.0-1.l0olq8++os.osx.x86_64+web.browser+web.cordova/mt-os.osx.x86_64/dev_bundle/server-lib/node_modules/fibers/future.js:280
                        throw(ex);
                        ^

TypeError: Cannot read property 'appId' of undefined
    at meteorInstall.imports.startup.server.useraccounts-configuration.js (imports/startup/server/useraccounts-configuration.js:9:12)
    at fileEvaluate (packages/modules-runtime/.npm/package/node_modules/install/install.js:153:1)
    at Module.require (packages/modules-runtime/.npm/package/node_modules/install/install.js:82:1)
    at Module.Mp.import (/Users/sammyunterman/.meteor/packages/modules/.0.7.5.1f9ncrv++os+web.browser+web.cordova/npm/node_modules/reify/lib/runtime.js:70:16)
    at meteorInstall.imports.startup.server.index.js (imports/startup/server/index.js:1:1)
    at fileEvaluate (packages/modules-runtime/.npm/package/node_modules/install/install.js:153:1)
    at Module.require (packages/modules-runtime/.npm/package/node_modules/install/install.js:82:1)
    at Module.Mp.import (/Users/sammyunterman/.meteor/packages/modules/.0.7.5.1f9ncrv++os+web.browser+web.cordova/npm/node_modules/reify/lib/runtime.js:70:16)
    at meteorInstall.server.main.js (server/main.js:1:8)
    at fileEvaluate (packages/modules-runtime/.npm/package/node_modules/install/install.js:153:1)
Exited with code: 1
Your application is crashing. Waiting for file change.
```

Comment: Look in the imports/startup/server/useraccounts-configuration.js file on line 9.

Comment: Thank you! It was the facebook ServiceConfig

Comment: For me I just specified `MONGO_URL` like `MONGO_URL="mongodb://localhost:27017/db" meteor --settings settings-local.json`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thank you @king-julian

It was the facebook `ServiceConfiguration`method in /imports/startup/server/useracounts-configuration.js.